# how to remove the dotted line from an anchor tag or Link tag in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am currently using react-burger-menu to make a side nav bar that opens and closes. Inside the nav bar, the content is wrapped around the anchor tag which makes it a link and it has a dotted line underneath. I tried so many thing to get rid of the dotted line but wasn't successful. The image below shows what I mean by the dotted lines.

[image]

```
a, a:active, a:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

```
<Menu>
   <a href="#" className="menu-item">  Home </a>

   <a className="menu-item" href="#">  Burgers </a>

   <a className="menu-item" href="#">  Pizzas </a>

   <a className="menu-item" href="#">  Desserts </a>
</Menu>
```

I have tried css styling like the one above but it made no difference. Any idea or tips I can use to make the dotted line disappear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would need to see developer tools to see what's going on; you could try adding "outline: none !important;" and see if it takes priority.

Comment: I have also tried doing that but wasn't successful.

Comment: try applying it to ".menu-item" instead of "a" selector

Comment: are you able to make a codesandbox ?  https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Inspect the actual css rules that apply to those elements by inspecting in your browser  dev tools element inspector. Then write more specific selector to overwrite existing rule(s). You can even write them in the dev tools inspector to test

Comment: So after trying to remake this in the sandbox, it seems like the dotted lines are not appearing. So, its probably somewhere in my code that is messing up the css

Comment: That may not even be an outline...it could be a dotted border and it may not even be on the `<a>`. Far too many unknowns here

Comment: found my mistake. Like you guys said it was a dotted border that was surrounding the anchor. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`react-burger-menu` does not force any styling, it seems this dotted style is inherited from some where else, you should use `text-decoration: none;` to override the dotted styles, but I suggest provide this style only to the menu items to avoid css global inheritance

```js
<Menu className="my-menu">
   <a href="#" className="menu-item">  Home </a>
   <a className="menu-item" href="#">  Burgers </a>
   <a className="menu-item" href="#">  Pizzas </a>
   <a className="menu-item" href="#">  Desserts </a>
</Menu>
```

Then in css, apply style to this menu items

```css
.my-menu .menu-item {
    text-decoration: none;
    ...
}
```

You can also try to inline css styles in react components using `style` prop

```js
<Menu className="my-menu">
   <a href="#" style={{ textDecoration: 'none !important' }}>  Home </a>
</Menu>
```

This is not practical but a good way to debug your issue, and in all ways always avoid `!important` in your styles.

Comment: @ShalinPatel All we can do is guess unless you provide a [mcve] that displays the actual issue in browser

Comment: Then it might be a css specificity issue, or your css file is not being imported/compile properly as a last guess you can try inline styles and see if things changed, otherwise as @charlietfl said it's impossible to figure this out without more info

Comment: I am new to react and css so how would I put something like this into inline css. ( a, a:active, a:focus {
   outline: none;
})

Comment: @ShalinPatel You will need to learn how to inspect elements and there style rules in browser dev tools (F12) elements inspector. Or provide a link to a live example we can inspect in browser

Comment: @ShalinPatel I updated my answer on how to use inline styles in React